# Calculate minutes between two or more timestamps in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-timestamp

My question: is there a way to calculate the difference between two timestamps with a SQL query?
I have a database table (MySQL 5.6) with different timestamps:

```
id  start_time          end_time            employee
1   2020-02-01 06:00:00 2020-02-01 13:00:00 Mark
2   2020-02-01 06:00:00 2020-02-01 12:30:00 David
3   2020-02-01 07:00:00 2020-02-01 14:00:00 Donald
4   2020-02-01 07:00:00 2020-02-01 13:00:00 Harry
```

I want to calculate the difference in minutes between every record in the table, i.e.: the difference of record with id 1 is 13:00:00 - 06:00:00 = 7 hours = 420 minutes. I want to calculate this for every record in the table and at the end summing up all the minutes. How can I do this?

I've already tried

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2020-01-02 06:00:00', '2020-01-02 13:00:00');
```

but how to use this with all the records without hardcoding all the timestamps by myself?

Can I use something like

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, 'start_time', 'end_time') AS totalMinutes ?
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace a hard coded value with a column name :) ..... no quotes :)

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried but I got an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'start_time' in 'field list'. But the name of the column is right.. ;-)

Comment: Well that quite possibly might be because the columns are called `start_time` and `end_time` and not `start_date` :)

Comment: Haha that was a typo but don't know what goes wrong. Never mind, I have the resolution (see post below) . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea, that uses the correct column names witout a quote as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I would expect this to do what you want:

```
select t.*,
       timestampdiff(minute, start_time, end_time) as minutes
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into a view, if you want it readily available:

```
create v_t as
    select t.*,
           timestampdiff(minute, start_time, end_time) as minutes
    from t;
```

In later versions, you can add a computed column:

```
alter table t add minutes int generated always as
    (timestampdiff(minute, start_time, end_time));
```

Comment: Thanks, this will help me!